# Sending salaam to prophet Muhammad (s.a.w.) during prayer

Tags: salat

Will my salah be invalidated if I send salam to prophet (s.a.w) if his name comes in the zammi surah? Or should I send salaam after salaah?

Comment: Are you doing it loudly or in secret? And what is the zammi surah?

Comment: @Medi1Saif zammi surah= part of Quran recited after surah al fatiha. I would like to know in both cases, and if I am behind imam.

Answer (score 2):

This may not fully answer your question, but it is recommended to recite the quran and interact with it. This means if you read a verse including a du'a in Quran you are allowed to say Ameen. If you read a verse about Allah's mercy you may ask Allah for his mercy and if you read a verse of punishment you may ask Allah for forgiveness etc.. it is recommended to say subhan Allah if you passed by a verse praising Allah like [87:1](http://legacy.quran.com/87/1) etc.. But as I understood this this would be allowed if you did so in secret or alone.

As a follower behind an Imam that would imply that you are free to send Greetings or Salam to our beloved Prophet at least in secret. As an Imam I wouldn't recommend doing this as for example it is not allowed to say "balaa بلى" affirming and answering the Question after reciting [95:8](http://legacy.quran.com/95/8) etc. because this statement is not part of the Quran, and some listeners might think it would be!

[بلى](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%A8%D9%84%D9%89/) means: certainly, truly, indeed in Arabic.